# HTML - Paytm Gateway integration issue

Tags: javascript, html, paytm

I am able to get a response from the paytm page which is valid HTML when I hit the /theia/processTransaction API.

Once I click the login button on the paytm payment page, I get the below error:
Refused to display 'https://accounts-uat.paytm.com/oauth2/login/otp?response_type=code&scope=paytm&theme=pg-otp&redirectUri=https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/oauthResponse&loginData=3xdouy0ysyvijkaokq2v:easypa39248810104558:WEB:undefined:MANUAL:E5402105B61053829144648F59EEF1F8.easypa392488101045583xdouy0ysyvijkaokq2v&clientId=paytm-pg-client-staging' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

How to I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. Paytm does not allow us to launch its gateway in an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Calling different API in IFrame is "cross-origin communication": The window.postMessage() method safely enables cross-origin communication between Window objects; e.g., between a page and a pop-up that it spawned, or between a page and an iframe embedded within it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

this is working for me not for paytm but for other payment gateways(PayUmoney).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does payu gateway work in an iframe?